# Cannot show data/logs on localhost/Git Bash using log_message

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, git-bash, logfile

I use `Codeigniter` and I want to show my logs in my localhost browser or Git Bash for log messages, I tried but doesn't work.

I use this in my *config.php* :

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

This is my `log_message`:

```
log_message('error',print_r($data, true));
```

I tried to run `$ tail -f application/logs` but no log file appears.

Is there anything or anyone that will help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logs saved in a php file with name format `log-Y-m-d.php`. So try like this

```
$ tail -f application/logs/log-2018-05-07.php
```

git bash result

[image]

Comment: It works! so It's just the log file with date that i will try to run and  I just see the log file in my log folder. Thanks a lot. You saved my day :)